# unir 2 tablas con fechas diferentes

Tags: mysql, union, inner

Hola a todos tengo 2 tablas en mysql con datos similares quiero unirlos por el campo fecha, pero tengo el detalle que en cada tabla no siempre tendrán habrá una fecha igual es decir algo como esto

Tabla 1

| Fecha | cantidad1 |
| --- | --- |
| 01-29-2021 | 25 |
| 02-13-2021 | 10 |
| 03-14-2021 | 45 |

Tabla 2

| Fecha | cantidad2 |
| --- | --- |
| 01-29-2021 | 10 |
| 02-10-2021 | 12 |
| 03-14-2021 | 4 |

he intentando con un union y después agrupar por el campo fecha pero me agrupa también las cantidades

Update: este es el código
`SELECT grupo.day_date as Fecha, sum(grupo.cantidad) as total FROM  ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') as day_date, COUNT(id) AS cantidad  FROM shirts GROUP BY Fecha UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y')  as day_date, COUNT(id) AS cantidad FROM leads GROUP BY day_date) AS grupo group by Fecha`

Quiero que se muestren en columnas diferentes, intente esto:

`SELECT * FROM (  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m-%d-%Y') as Fecha, COUNT(id) as cantidad1, '' as cantidad2  FROM leads GROUP BY Fecha UNION ALL SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m-%d-%Y') as Fecha, '' as cantidad1, COUNT(id) as cantidad2 FROM test GROUP BY Fecha) AS grupo group by Fecha order by Fecha`

pero no funciona, el resultado que busco es algo como esto:

Tabla resultado

| Fecha | cantidad1 | cantidad2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-29-2021 | 25 | 10 |
| 02-10-2021 | 0 | 12 |
| 02-13-2021 | 10 | 0 |
| 03-14-2021 | 45 | 4 |

Comment: Buenas, por favor mira [ask] para saber cómo comentar, pero debes agregar el código de lo que haces o tienes para entender mejor que haces

Comment: Gracias  Excorpion ya edite mi post

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de agrupar y unir, mejor une y agrupa:

1. Une las tablas identificando el origen
2. Agrupa por fecha, distinguiendo en la sumatoria el origen

```
SELECT date_format(created_at,'%m-%d-%Y') Fecha
     , sum(u.tabla=1) cantidad1
     , sum(u.tabla=2) cantidad2
  FROM ( SELECT 1 tabla, created_at, id
           FROM leads
         UNION 
         SELECT 2 tabla, created_at, id
           FROM test
       ) u
  GROUP BY created_at
```

Para que funcione tu idea original sólo te faltaba sumar los resultados:

```
SELECT Fecha
     , sum(cantidad1)
     , sum(cantidad2)
```